# Split string with specific formation Angular 6, Typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I am trying to use regex with javascript, I have the following list:

> word1 @['id1', 'name1']@ @['id2', 'name2']@ @['id3', 'name3']@ word2
>   @['id4', 'name4']@ word3 @['id5', 'name5']@

I want to detect everything has: @[' ..... ']@ and split them like that:

```
word1
@['id1', 'name1']@
@['id2', 'name2']@
@['id3', 'name3']@
word2
@['id4', 'name4']@
word3
@['id5', 'name5']@
```

So I can read the id and the name later to be able to create a link:

```
<a href="url/[id]">[name]</a>
```

I have tried this regex:

```
[@\['](.)*['\]@]
```

But it is just mark everything from the first @[' till the end at name5.

Simple code:

```
const reg = /[@\['](.)*['\]@]]/;
const arr = content.split(reg);
```

If anybody knows how to split it, I would appreciate sharing the solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `split`, consider `.match`, which may make the logic easier: either match word characters, or match `@[`, followed by any characters, followed by `]@`:

```
\w+|@\[.*?\]@
```

```js
const input = `word1 @['id1', 'name1']@ @['id2', 'name2']@ @['id3', 'name3']@ word2 @['id4', 'name4']@ word3 @['id5', 'name5']@`;
console.log(input.match(/\w+|@\[.*?\]@/g));
```

If the inside of the `[]` may contain `]@`s you don't want to match, such as `@['id1', ']@', 'name1']@`, then you'll need a bit more logic - inside the `[]`s, repeat groups of `'` or `"` delimited strings:

```
\w+|@\[(?:(?:'[^']+'|"[^"]+")(?:, *|(?=\])))*\]@
```

https://regex101.com/r/rDW2iD/1

Comment: Ooh, I missed adding \w at the beginning. Thanks! I guess this is the solution I am looking for!

Comment: how to get an array of the result?

Comment: Press "Run code snippet" - the `.match` returns an array of all results

Comment: It works. I forgot adding g at the end to match all. Thanks! this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You may split the string using

```
s.split(/\s*(@\[.*?]@)\s*/).filter(Boolean)
```

See the JS demo:

```js
var s = "word1 @['id1', 'name1']@ @['id2', 'name2']@ @['id3', 'name3']@ word2 @['id4', 'name4']@ word3 @['id5', 'name5']@";
console.log(s.split(/\s*(@\[.*?]@)\s*/).filter(Boolean));
```

The pattern matches 0+ whitespaces, then captures `@[`, any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, up to the first `]@`, and then matches without capturing 0+ whitespaces. The captured substrings land in the resulting array, and `.filter(Boolean)` removes empty items.